# How to remove old facuet?

Tags: faucet

Although I watched a few youtube videos to replace old facuet, but I still have no idea to deal with my case.

See the images.
[image: Single handle facuet.]

From the bottom
[image: image2]

And you can see the cold water and hot water connector are in the left and right. The middle one white plastic is for side spray.
[image: image3]

I am not sure how to take off the set. Should I deal with the plastic one?
If I buy a new one, what should I buy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the faucet (looking at the center photo) there is a brass hex nut (just above the braided plastic hose connector) that is tightened to hold the "C" shaped spacer and the faucet securely to the sink basin. You can use a Basin wrench (it has a swiveling head on a long handle) or an adjustable crescent wrench with a short  handle. Either way loosening the nut will enable the faucet to be removed from the sink. You will also want to shut the water supply off on the hot and cold lines first.

Comment: Should I buy a 4 holes faucet?

Comment: The configuration of the new faucet will need to be shaped so that the supply lines will fit through the sink openings. When you remove the original single handled faucet count the opening on the sink edge. If you count 3 evenly spaced openings the two outer most openings should be spaced 8 inches on each openings center (O/C). The 8" spacing is commonly used for a dual handled faucet. You also have the option of installing a post mounted faucet in the center opening and capping the un-used openings with caps made for this purpose.